# Lotus Script to make text Blink

Tags: lotusscript

How to make text Blink using Lotus Script ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use programmable table rows to make the text blink.

1. Create a table with 2 rows
2. Write the same text in 2 rows of a table
3. Set the table borders to zero
4. Go to the 'Table Rows' tab of the table properties box
5. Choose 'Show Only One Row At A Time' option
6. Under 'Which row to display' section, select row every xxxx milliseconds
7. Optional - Give an effect using 'Transition when switching rows' section
8. Launch the form and see the text blinking

Answer (score 0):

LotusScript can't make text "blink" like a web page. It's not a capability of LotusScript or the Lotus Notes object model.

Comment: Gosh. I think that's the first thing I've ever heard that has improved my feelings towards Lotus Notes! :)